# MATLAB: How to vectorize typecast() of a million values

Tags: matlab

I have a dataset 'data" of type uint8 that has 1 million rows and 16 columns. I am using the following code to convert them into 'double' values. How do I "vectorize" it to make it faster?

```
for i = 1:length(data)
   value1(i) = typecast(data(i,1:8), 'double');
    value2(i) = typecast(data(i,9:16),'double');
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Since each row represents a `double` value, and MATLAB stores data column-wise, transposing `data` (with `.'`) causes the matrix to contain the values in the right order to be converted in a single `typecast` call. We also need to reshape to a vector, which doesn't change the order of the data in memory (with `(:)`).

```
value1 = data(:,1:8).';
value1 = typecast(value1(:), 'double');
value2 = data(:,9:16).';
value2 = typecast(value2(:), 'double');
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried it without the dot operator before posting here and it didn't work. Your suggestion didn't work either. What does the dot operator doing in this case. Below is the error I get:


    Error using typecast
    The first input argument must be a vector.

Comment: Ah, that error makes sense, it needs a reshape. I'll fix the answer. The `.'` is the transpose operator. `'` is conjugate transpose. There is only a difference for complex values, but it's good to get in the habit of using the right operator to prevent unexpected results.